# break up recursive function in php

Tags: php

What is the best way to break up a recursive function that is using a ton of resources

For example:

```
function do_a_lot(){

   //a lot of code and processing is done here
   //it takes a lot of execution time

   if($true){

      //if true we have to do all of that processing again
      do_a_lot();

   }

}
```

Is there anyway to make the server only have to take the brunt of the first execution and then break up the recursion into separate processes? Or am I dreaming?

Comment: How about turning it into an iterative function?

Comment: @Gumbo: this will not make the process faster unless some environment loading task are used in the processing block.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if your function is using up that much of your system's resources, I'd most likely refactor my code. However, it's not truly multithreading, but you could perhaps look at using [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) to fork your process.

Answer (score 0):

One of the rule of PHP is "**Share nothing**". That means every PHP process is independant and shares nothing with the others. So if you want to break your execution on several PHP process you'll have to store the data somewhere. It can be a **memcached** storage, or a **database**, or the **session**, as you want.

Then you'll need to '**fork**' your PHp process. They're solutions available to get this done on the server side. IMHO this is all hacks. Dangerous and not minded in the PHP/web way. With the exception of '**work queues**' tools.

I think the nicest way is to break your task with **ajax**. This will allow you a clean user interface and will avoid any long response timeout in the web process. i.e. show a 'working zone' to you user, then ask in ajax for next step of the job (first one), get response (in server side stor you response), then ask for next step, store new response and respond , next step, etc. You can even add a 'stop that stuff' function on the client side.

You can check as well for 'php work queue' on google.

Comment: can the downvoters explain their feelings? Am I completly wrong? I'm open on discussions.

Comment: **1.** nothing to do with ajax, if this mean for CLI **2.** shifting to external resources it will eventually jam-up the external resources if the job does not clear on-time. **3.** fork is not a hack, **is a proper solution for many things, such as apache**

Comment: 1- you're right, but php is mostly not use on cli, I should have stated that this response was for php as an apache module in web env. 2- I don't understand you 3 - I was talking of forking inside PHP (inside apache), try to get one web requests handled by several PHP process. Of course I'm not talking about forking as a general design pattern. Thanks for these remarks, my position was maybe not precise enough.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a long running task, divide and conquer with [gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php)